# Facebook comments - gender and location of users

Tags: facebook-graph-api

Is there a way to get additional data for users that commented on a post on Facebook? So far I'm getting the message, the id and name of the user with this:

```
GET https://graph.facebook.com/POST_ID/comments?fields=message,from.id,from.name
```

I would like to additionally fetch from.gender and from.location, but this does not seem to work. Is there any other way?

Answer (score 0):

The `from` object for a given comment only contains `id` and `name` elements.

`id` in the `from` object pertains to the user who posted a given comment. Once you have `id` you can query the graph API again against that user for their user details. However, you may or may not be able to retrieve `location` for any given user: their privacy settings may or may not expose it, or you may not have adequate permissions to retrieve more than the most generic information for that user.

You should always be able to retrieve `gender` and `locale` from a given user's endpoint in the API, however. Not that I would rely on `locale` for location information per se, but it may be at least marginally useful depending on your needs.